# running sh command in jenkinsfile to find all extensio file in the folder

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am running a shell script within the Jenkins pipeline and i want to run find command to get all extension files and copy them to the scan folder inside the "AppName" folder

here's the code:

```
stage("SCA Check"){
        node("default"){
          checkout scm
          
          conf.findAll { key, value -> key.contains("token.") }.each { key, value ->
            tokens << string(credentialsId: value, variable: key.replace('token.',''))
          }
          
          withEnv(vars) {
            withCredentials(tokens){
              dir(dirpath) {
                dir(AppName) {
                 git url: gitURL,
                     credentialsId: 'bitbucket-https-url-rdonly',
                     branch: branchName
                   }  
                sh """#!/bin/bash
                set
                echo '${scaInfo}'
                python --version
                cp Action.py '${AppName}' && cd '${AppName}' && mkdir scan
                "find . -regex '.*\.\(sql\|conf\|py\|csv\|coveragerc\|css\|eot\|etlconf\|hql\|html\|idx\|ini\|js\|json\|log\|map\|md\|pack\|pdf\|sample\|sh\|svg\|ttf\|txt\|woff\|woff2\)$' -exec cp {} scan/ \;"
                echo find
                cd scan && zip scan.zip * && mv scan.zip .. && cd ..
                python Action.py '${scaInfo}'
                """
              } 
            }
          } 
        }}            
       }
```

But this gives error while running pipeline:

```
Branch event
Obtained jenkinsfile from 1ace31daa88df82dd21cb4a04251065b78562fdf
Running in Durability level: PERFORMANCE_OPTIMIZED
[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 108: unexpected char: '\' @ line 108, column 22.
                find . -regex '.*\.\(sql\|conf\|py\|csv\|coveragerc\|css\|eot\|etlconf\|hql\|html\|idx\|ini\|js\|json\|log\|map\|md\|pack\|pdf\|sample\|sh\|svg\|ttf\|txt\|woff\|woff2\)$' -exec cp {} scan/ \;
                        ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
```

How would i resolve the issue so that i would get all the extension files within the dir & sub-dir & copy to the "scan" folder so that i would go ahead and create zip file of the folder and ship to different location

Comment: You have to escape all  \ with  \\. The same for `$` where it's not a var name.

Comment: do you mean something like this ```find . -regex '.*\\.\\(sql\\|conf\\|py\\|csv\\|coveragerc\\|css\\|eot\\|etlconf\\|hql\\|html\\|idx\\|ini\\|js\\|json\\|log\\|map\\|md\\|pack\\|pdf\\|sample\\|sh\\|svg\\|ttf\\|txt\\|woff\\|woff2\\)$' -exec cp {} scan/ \\;```

Comment: And `\$`. BTW Why not to use native zip step that could filter files/folders ? https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#zip-create-zip-file

Comment: Thanks @daggett! It really works!